# Is this subordinate clause missing an independent clause?

Tags: grammaticality

> However, ♦ when the Terrorism Prevention and Investigation Measures Act 2011 retains
>   the power to relocate individuals to another part of the country without consent under
>   powers for the secretary of state to impose enhanced TPIM notices. ♦ This, essentially
>   emergency power may only be used, when Parliament is not in session, i.e. between the
>   dissolution of a Parliament and the fi rst Queen’s Speech of the next Parliament.

Source: p 72, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

Are there problems with the subordinate clause that I've surrounded with lozenges (♦)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a problem. This is as you say a subordinate clause—specifically, a temporal clause headed by *when*—and there is no head clause to which it is subordinated.

I think this is probably an editing mistake: *when* is likely left over from an earlier draft and should be deleted.